# Realizar acción según item en una ListView

Tags: java, android

Quiero realizar una acción diferente según el item seleccionado de un Listview, por ejemplo ya tengo el que redirige a una pagina web, pero lo que no se hacer es que tome el numero telefónico de la lista y lo lleve al teclado telefónico para marcar.

aquí el código:

```
    public class ListClass extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;

    private String getPhoneNumber(){
        TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager;
        mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        return mTelephonyManager.getLine1Number();
    }

    private String Itemlist[] = new String[]{"Nombre", "Horario", "+567423124", "direccion", "pagina web"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kameleon_class);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.kameleonlist);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, Itemlist);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                int posicion = position;

                if (position == 2) {

                    String itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),getPhoneNumber().getClass());



                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if(position == 4) {

                    String url = "http://www.paginaweb.com";


                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent2.setData(Uri.parse(url));



                    startActivity(intent2);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Al dar clic obtienes el valor del teléfono en el `ListView` mediante:

```
String itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

La llamada se realizaría mediante un [`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) para realizar [llamadas telefónicas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL):

```
String itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + itemValue));

// Validación para dispositivos que no puedan realizar llamadas (SecurityException).
try {
    startActivity(phoneIntent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No puedes realizar llamadas.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Agrega a tu `AndroidManifest.xml` los permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue de mucha utilidad el metodo que agregaste me funcionó (supongo) ya que al hacer click me muestra el mensaje de que no puede realizar llamadas, ahora no lo puedo probar ya que es una aplicacion que utiliza googlemaps y no me muestra el mapa el telefono para ver si puede realizar la llamada.

Comment: Deseas realizar una llamada al dar clic en un teléfono del ListView o cargar Google Maps? No entiendo porque cargas un mapa si en tu pregunta indicas que es un ListView.

Comment: Claro lo que quiero que haga es que al seleccionar el telefono del listview como string, que lo tome y lo lleve al teclado telefonico del emulador o del equipo

Answer (score -1):

Para marcar un numero:

```
String number = "+56966996313";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +number));
startActivity(intent);
```

Debes agregar el permiso respectivo en el manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Comment: Estimado muchas gracias, pero no me funciona. Sale un mensaje de "Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with 'checkPermission') or explicitly handle a potential 'SecurityException' " esto sale en  startActivity(intent);

agregue el permiso en el manifest

Comment: Estás usando android 6.0?